# Unity3d IOS app: Error opening third-party application using Application.OpenURL

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity ios app that I want to trigger the opening of another Unity ios app that I previously developed and released on App Store.

In Unity:

```
Application.OpenURL("my-app://");
```

In my Xcode build I am adding the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes flag

```
LSApplicationQueriesSchemes: "my-app"
```

But it does not open on my iphone. The console of my iphone shows the following error:

```
ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme <private>
```

Whats strange is that this is only the case when the app is downloaded from App Store. If I build my-app directly from XCode, then it opens fine. It seems like there is something with the URL scheme I am not understanding.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in first you developed app. 
don't give LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in current app.